# Update a declared tabled dynamic column name

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am running a SQL loop to update a declared table. Please have a look at the following

```
DECLARE @tblResults TABLE (  [idx]              INT IDENTITY(0,1)
                            ,[cityCode]         VARCHAR(3)
                            ,[month_1_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_2_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_3_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_4_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_5_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_6_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_7_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_8_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_9_perc]     INT
                            ,[month_10_perc]    INT
                            ,[month_11_perc]    INT
                            ,[month_12_perc]    INT)
```

> loop will start here

```
DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @sqlExec VARCHAR(500) = CONACT('UPDATE @tblResults SET [month_', @colName, '_perc] = 9; 

EXECUTE(@sql)
```

> loop

This obviously doesn't work - I am trying to find a work around if any -
Open to suggestions

Comment: Why do u want to use Concat ?

Comment: CONCAT() isn't is the problem here. could string build as well. just prefer CONTACT()

Comment: If you have to update *columns* one at a time, you probably need a table where month, perc are fields. Or you are looking to *pivot* the results of some query. Or you are using a loop where a query with proper groupings and aggregations would provide the correct results.

Comment: If you want to produce statistics per month and display them in columns you can use PIVOT with the list of months. If you want a running average per month, you could use `AVG() OVER(...)`.

Comment: Are you using `IDENTITY` to generate row numbers for the results? You can use `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(...)` to do that in the query

Comment: In order to use dynamic SQL to update a table variable, the table variable needs to be created and populated *at the same scope*. This means one huge string that includes the table declaration, inserts, and then the series of updates. You won't be able to run each update individually in a loop. But maybe you should just structure your table differently - if you had a *row* for each month instead of a *column*, you wouldn't need any dynamic SQL at all.

Comment: Thanks @AaronBertrand! I will end up going with your advice

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @colName VARCHAR(15)
DECLARE @sqlExec VARCHAR(500)

SET @colName = '1'
SET @sqlExec = 'UPDATE @tblResults SET [month_' + @colName + '_perc] = 9' 

EXECUTE( @sqlExec)
```

Comment: this sadly isn't what i am after - this would work if i was updated a table in SQL. I am how ever create a table in a declared variable and then trying to update the declared table through EXECUTE().

Comment: @oldman what are you after? Why use a lot or separate columsn per month? What is the actual problem you want to solve? Most likely (almost certainly) you can solve it much more efficiently without loops and dynamic sql

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding **how** and **why** it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

I am a bit confused with your request, but if you really want to use a loop

```
declare @i int = 1;
declare @sqlUpdate nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE tblResults SET ';
declare @sql;

while @i <= 12 
BEGIN

set @sql = @sqlUpdate + '[month_' + cast(@i as nvarchar(5)) + '_perc] = 9;' -- value?

print (@sql)
-- execute (@sql)

set @i = @i + 1;
END
```

Or you want to set same value to all columns in one go

```
declare @cols nvarchar(max)
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(col.name) + ' = 9' -- value?
                      from tempdb.sys.columns col
                        join tempdb.sys.tables tab on col.object_id = tab.object_id
                        where tempdb.tab.name = 'tblResults'
        FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
        ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
    ,1,1,'')  


declare @sql nvarchar(max) = 'UPDATE tblResults SET ' + @cols;

print (@sql)
-- execute (@sql)
```

Note, none of scripts are tested